# SAS prxchange to add a space into a string with a special characters

Tags: regex, sas

Hi I'm trying to replace  `125MG/5ML` with `125MG/5 ML`.
Here's my regex but its not inserting a space between `5` and `ML`.
How do I add a space and keep the '/' .

```
("s/125MG\/5ML/125MG\/ 5 ML /i",-1,OLD_WORD)
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the expected result (including a space _before_ the 5) when I run that as is.  Have you used PRXMATCH to confirm the match is working?

Comment: It works but I needed a regex that is more general, so I don't have to type  each string verbatim.  So Shenglin's code works for any general case of that pattern type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually need something more general, such as inserting a blank between digits and ML following digits+MG/, then the following may fit your bill:

```
data want;
input var $50.;
new=prxchange('s/(\d+MG\/\d+)ML/$1 ML/io',-1, var);
cards;
125MG/5ML adkdk
12MG/3ML
dkljsza 2455125MG/17ML
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data _null_;
string="125MG/5ML";
_string=prxchange('s/([^0-9]+)$/ $1/',-1,string);
put _all_;
run;
```